# How to remote debug two spring boot applications running in the same container with the same codebase but with different profiles?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, debugging, remote-debugging

I have two spring boot applications running in the same container with the same codebase but with different profiles.

One application is for production and the other is for test. Each application run under a different virtual host.

The container is tomcat and I've added this in `setenv.sh` :

```
CATALINA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=5005,server=y,suspend=n $CATALINA_OPTS"
```

With eclipse, I can create a debug configuration for Remote Java Application. I've set the Host to the test server host name.

But when I set a breakpoint, the production **AND** the test application trigger the breakpoint.

How to set the debugging environment such as only the test application triggers the breakpoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to create a way for verifying the current profile. You can add a environment to the object you want to debug:

```
public class SpringBean {
  @Autowired
  private Environment env;
  ...
}
```

You can set a breakpoint in any of its methods, right click it and edit its `Breakpoint properties...` like this:

[image]

Note `Conditional` and `Suspend when 'true'` selected. The breakpoint will only trigger, if current object belongs to the app that has `testProfile` activated.

**Note:**

You can also ad a singleton bean to your app that will make `env` statically accessible from any object in your app. In this case you can access `EnvHolder.env` in your breakpoint properties to check the current profile.

```
public class EnvHolder {
  public static Environment env;

  @Autowired
  public void setEnv(final Environment environment) {
      env = environment;
  }
}
```

However, if you do not have two distinct apps on tomcat with separate libraries, class loading issues could interfere with that approach.

If you cannot modify any classes in the app, you could try to insert hints about current profile into some thread bound object. For instance add a special suffix to thread name, but you would have to ensure that the name is cleaned when the thread ends its work in test app.

Comment: Your solution with the singleton bean works well and is less invasive than the first proposition. Thank you.