# How to deploy multiple wars in tomcat using eclipse and then be able to debug the code

Tags: eclipse, maven, debugging, tomcat, deployment

I am trying to setup an application, recently migrated to work with latest java version and tomcat, in eclispe. This application uses maven to generate two war files. I need to deploy these two war files to tomcat and be able to debug the code.

If I select the option in server to let eclipse take control over the deployment, whole application gets deployed and I am not able to access either of the modules using their context.

And if I choose to use tomcat installation, I have to manually copy the wars and run the server.Application runs but then I am not able to debug. I tried the remote debugging which worked but I was wondering if there is a cleaner approach on deploying two wars using eclipse and then access each app using its context.

Comment: Here is a related question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39834699/how-to-remote-debug-two-spring-boot-applications-running-in-the-same-container-w

Comment: Thanks but it does not answer my question. I am looking for a better way to deploy the wars and debug the code. I dont want to manually copy the wars. I tired the tomcat plugin but it did not work(maybe i did something wrong). I have around 4  pom files.

Comment: You can also use [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/).

Comment: I haven't done this with a multi-module project that produces two independent war files?  On the other hand, we do this all the time with single-war projects (using tomcat7 Maven plugin). We start each war on its own http port - with a distinct debug port. Then, we use two debug configurations - each one pointing at the proper debug port and source project.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what happens when you configure eclipse for localhost:8080/app1 and localhost:8080/app2 ? You're saying that does not work? And if I understand you correctly, that is what you want right? /app1 and /app2 on the same Tomcat instance?

Comment: @Usman Mutawakil - yes, but I don't know how to configure eclipse for two apps. I tried to play with run configuration but I could not make it to work. I can try doing that if you can point me in the right direction.

Comment: @Michael Peacock - Yeah, I have done it with one war and I was able to deploy and debug with multiple wars, I am not able to configure eclipse to deploy and use those wars fro different run configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I tried tons of things and finally I was able to deploy/debug the code. It required some tweaking on the run/debug configuration side and some changes in the launch classes to provide the necessary setup required to launch the applications.

Created different configuration based on the application which needed to be deployed and debugged.